# Best practices for a Password Management System

Tags: passwords

I'm working on a password management system which stores the passwords of a bunch of services (gmail, bank of america account, youtube etc). The user will be able to launch each of these services by logging into my application. The application will then POST the username and password associated with that service to that service's login url in a new tab and you will be immediately logged in. My question is, this method exposes the actual password of the user to the client side (since I'm creating a form with username and password, in plain text, as hidden fields and calling form.submit). I'm wondering is there any other method by which this can be achieved? How do all the password management sites work? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do it server side, what else can I say? Anyway, I can only see this as a learning experience, not something that would eventually go into production. cUrl could be a good start. Why do you use form.submit anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "formfill" in terms of access management terminology, if you are thinking about access gateway (http). If you are thinking about browser plugin, have a look at the firefox autofill plugin. And which finally reduces to single sign-on.
Single sign-on are done different ways,-

1. some servers uses active directory to store all the passwords and later access using the master password , i.e. the active directory password of that user to access his credentials.
2. Some uses SAML
3. Some uses e-directory

Whatever you use, if it is server-side application (e.g. Appache supports formfill), it parses all the forms based on form name or resource path and fills credentials based on the authenticated session from the user.